# What does とも mean here?

Tags: set-phrases

I couldn't get the expression below.

> 彼女は英語を話すのが得意で、**兄に勝るとも劣らぬくらいだ**。

Comment: what have you done to understand this sentence?  Give us a little more context, and we will be able to better cater an answer for your needs.

Comment: 勝るとも劣らない is a fixed expression. What does your dictionary say? http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E5%8B%9D%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82%E5%8A%A3%E3%82%89%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84

Comment: Aren't there typos in" 勝るとも劣らぬくらいだ"?

Comment: @Tommy タイポですか？どこも間違ってないと思いますけど。

Comment: @Chocolate Sorry! I didn't read well! lol It's actually 劣らぬ - くらい - だ. My bad! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(～に)勝るとも劣らない is a fixed expression meaning "be in no way inferior to; not at all inferior to; rival or surpass; compare favorably (with)" ([Source](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E5%8B%9D%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82%E5%8A%A3%E3%82%89%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84))

> まさる【勝る(優る)】...
>   「勝るとも劣らない（＝同等以上だ）」
>   （明鏡国語辞典）

> 勝(まさ)るとも劣(おと)ら◦ない
>   それ以上ではあっても劣っていることはない。互角またはそれ以上である。
>   （[デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/207928/meaning/m0u/)）

As you know, 劣らぬ is a literary way of saying 劣らない. (The ぬ originally is the attributive form of the archaic negative auxiliary ず)

> What does とも mean here?

The ～とも* is a conjunctive particle (接続助詞) meaning 「（たとえ）～ても」"(even) if~~". (勝る**とも**劣らない = 勝ることはあっ**ても**劣ることはない)
<sub>*とも sounds relatively archaic, and attaches to the terminal form/終止形 of verbs in 文語, the imperfective form/未然形 of verbs + the auxiliary う・よう in 口語, and the continuative form/連用形 of i-adjectives (Source: 明鏡国語辞典).</sub>

---

Example from Shogakukan's *Progressive Japanese-English Dictionary*:

> これは耐久性ではあちらのに**勝るとも劣りません**。
>   This is *no less* durable *than* that.